Identification of an old (black and white) drama/thriller with a twist
This one has been bugging me for years - I saw the film one afternoon about 15 years ago.
Its black and white, and quite old (poss 1930's).
It's set in Paris (or other European city) at some kind of 'Worlds fair'/Expo.
A young American woman arrives there with her Brother, who is expressing a few symptoms of illness.
The next day her brother is not in the room, but neither are any of his belongings - the staff in the hotel have no recollection of him being there, and the police she speaks to have no information about him arriving in the city.
Then there is a big 'hunt for the truth' - with accusations that the woman is insane or hysterical, and the Brother never existed.
Eventually it comes to light he was suffering from Smallpox (or some other highly communicable disease - and the 'authorities' have basically erased all trace of the brother to stop the story of the infection hitting the media and impacting the visitor numbers/profits of the Expo.
I've hunted online for what this might be - but only have the vague details about the plot - I've left out any spoiler tags, as due to the date of the film, its unlikely it'll be spoiling anything for anyone, and could help with identification!

Cool, might have to give this one a try! It reminds me of "Frantic" and "Unknown".

Could it be "So long at the Fair" (http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0042980/) ?

That's the one!
